# CSS color animate border-top property

Tags: css

I have a 4px border top with a blue color and I want to create a simple animation to indicate that something is loading.

```
body.loading {
    border-top: 3px black solid;
}
```

I want to have a black/white gradient and move it to make the effect. I found some examples for mouse over effects but in this case I want the animation to last forever only for the body.loading class.

I found an example but is using a background color not a border. (http://jsfiddle.net/aKhjk/1/). thank you for your guidance.

Comment: This can come to use: https://loading.io/css/

Comment: This is what you need . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmR6-R01nOs
Border cannot have gradient  , so we use a small trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a animation property for `bordertest`class

```
 animation: loading 3s linear infinite;
```

keyframe for the animation below:

```
@keyframes loading {
from {left: 0%; width: 0;z-index:100;}
to {left: 0; width: 100%;}
```

}

[demo](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/Kbxyvq)